# Updating the names of elements of a fs path character vector in R

Tags: r, regex, list, directory

I have a fs path character vector with a list of file names like these:

```
path/to/folder/output_1_CR.csv
path/to/folder/output_2_CR.csv
...
path/to/folder/output_22_CR.csv
...
path/to/folder/output_67_CR.csv
```

Here's the code I used to read in these output files into a fs path character vector:

```
CR_A_paths <- fs::dir_ls(path = "/path/to/folder", regexp = "[CR].csv$")
```

I want to update the names of the files with single digits in their file name (e.g. output_1_CR.csv, output_5_CR.csv) such that there's a 0 before the single digit (i.e. output_1_CR.csv becomes output_01_CR.csv)

Any idea on efficient ways to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str_replace`:

```
 to <- stringr::str_replace(CR_A_paths, "\\d+", ~sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(.x)))
 to

[1] "path/to/folder/output_01_CR.csv"  "path/to/folder/output_02_CR.csv" 
[3] "path/to/folder/output_22_CR.csv"  "path/to/folder/output_67_CR.csv "
```

Now to update the names use:

```
 file.rename(CR_A_paths,to)
```

---

```
CR_A_paths <- c("path/to/folder/output_1_CR.csv", "path/to/folder/output_2_CR.csv", 
"path/to/folder/output_22_CR.csv", "path/to/folder/output_67_CR.csv "
)
```

Comment: thank you, this is helpful! is there any way i can edit the file names themselves before reading with fs::dir_ls? Currently, the solution updates the list of the file names in R but not the actual file names themselves. Just curious!

Comment: @jo_ just use `file.rename(CR_A_paths, stringr::str_replace(CR_A_paths, "\\d+", ~sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(.x))))`

Comment: What if I want to replace the original single digit output files with the updated filename? In other words, there's only output_01_CR.csv in my folder, and not both output_01_CR.csv and output_1_CR.csv. Thank you!!

Comment: The code renames the file accordingle. The two files should not exist. ie `list.files(pat = "[CR].csv$")` should list all the files with the `CR` and then you rename them. If you have both `01` and `1` that is not renaming but rather copying